# Mvvmcross Android google maps, unable to bind zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have followed the N+1 day example and built a mapping app that show the center coordinate. The value is 2-way-bound so move the map changes the value as well. Now I would like to bind the zoomlevel but for unknown reason the value only get initialized but not updated. Closer inspection I found the "Set" part of the ZoomLevel property in the viewmodel only got called once.

Here is some code snipplet:

In the model view I have this property:

```
private float _zoomLevel;
public float ZoomLevel {
    get { return _zoomLevel; }
    set {
        _zoomLevel = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ZoomLevel);
    }
}
```

In MyMapFragment, I have properties Center and ZoomLevel which looks quite alike:

```
private LatLng _center;
public LatLng Center{
get { return _center; }
set {
        _center = value;    
        var center = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(value, ZoomLevel);
        Map.MoveCamera(center);
    }
}

private float _zoomLevel;
public float ZoomLevel{
    get { return _zoomLevel; }
    set {
        _zoomLevel = value;
        var zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(Center, value);
        Map.MoveCamera(zoom);
    }
}
```

And in the CreateBinding() method, I have:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyMapFragment, CityGuideMapViewModel>();
set.Bind(this).For(v => v.Center).To(vm =>  vm.Center).WithConversion(new LocationToLatLngValueConverter(), null);
set.Bind(this).For(v => v.ZoomLevel).To(vm => vm.ZoomLevel);
set.Apply();
```

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything I am missing?

You're not currently telling MvvmCross when the user changes the zoom level.

You need to include some code that detects and signals the map zoom level change in the `MyMapFragment` - e.g. you need to use an `OnCameraChangeListener` and to fire a ZoomLevelChanged event:

```
public event EventHandler ZoomLevelChanged;

private float _zoomLevel;
public float ZoomLevel{
    get { return _zoomLevel; }
    set {
        _zoomLevel = value;
        var zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(Center, value);
        Map.MoveCamera(zoom);
    }
}
```